# Как перейти с формы на action методом post?

Tags: laravel

Только начинаю осваивать laravel. Поставил на openserver. В файле 'app/http/routes.php' прописал следующее:

```
    Route::post('/comments', function () {  
    print_r($_POST);  
    });
```

В папке public создал форму

```
    <form action="/comments" method="POST">
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name"><br/>
        Comment:<br>
        <textarea name="comment"></textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="add">
    </form>
```

После того как нажимаю на submit мне в ответ приходит

[image: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:]

Учу по урокам на ютубе, все делаю как лектор говорит, у него все работает как надо, а я вот в ступор в этом месте впал, знания мои пока ограничены только тем как прописать роут новый, дальше не могу двинуться)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Явно же написано в чем ошибка...
Не передаете `csrf_token`.
Ко всем маршрутам `post` - методом применяется `app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class`.
Это делается в целях безопасности и исключения повторных отправок форм.
Собственно решение проблемы...
1. Добавить в форму `csrf_token` это можно сделать так:

```
<form>
    {{csrf_field()}}
</form>
```

либо так:

```
    <form>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
    </form>
```

либо, если используете `laravelcollective\html` - хэлперы, то достаточно открыть форму так:

```
{{Form::open()}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

2. В классе `app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class` добавить Ваш маршрут в исключение. Этот метод используется если вы этого намеренно хотите, ну... напрмер для `api` или аплоада файлов и т.д.